# Exporting from revit to create VR experiance

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, revit-api, autodesk

is there a way to fix this problem coming from revit and going to (in this case) twinmotion or unity eventually? The problem is the flickering walls and other objects(see photo 3), I suppose they are one on top of another and thats why its doing that.

I'll attach three photos, one an image of what's supposed to look like, two what revit looks like and three what it looks like in twinmotion.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Revit API question so the 'revit-api' tag should not be used in this case.  Please remove it.

Otherwise, it looks like you have overlapping wall geometry, perhaps from a linked file?  Turn off all links in the view to see if the problem goes away.